# Problem with IE in a menu with CSS

Tags: css

I have a strange problem with IE in a CSS menu.

Have an `<li>` with a text and an `<ul>` (with position absolute) and `<li>` inside.

In Mozilla Firefox the sub `<ul>` assumes the desired position (see picture below).

In IE the text forces the sub `<ul>` to go forward. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```
li {
float:left;
width:auto;
}
li ul {
left:-999em;
margin-left:0;
margin-top:5px;
padding:0;
position:absolute;
width:150px;
}
li:hover { 
left:auto 
}
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot see your image.  Can you type out the HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sarfraz, thanks for your quick answer...I've tried your suggestions and didn't work, and then after some days I've discovered..it was a file created recently with ANSI codification. I have all files UTF-8 and the problem solved converting the ANSI file to UTF-8 with Notepad++. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are three suggestions coming in my mind.

1 - You can use the [Eric Meyer's reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/).
2 - You may go for [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) and make IE behave like standard compliant browser.
3 - Unrecommended way is to use IE6 hack like this:

```
* html ul li{
  /* your styles */
}
```